# ExtJs 4.2 treepanel

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm stuck creating an example of a tree panel.I only obtain an infinite tree.What am I doing wrong?

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('mdlDocumentosTree', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[
        {name:'id',                 type:'string',      mapping:''},
        {name:'text',               type:'string',      mapping:''},
        {name:'leaf',               type:'boolean',     mapping:''},
        {name:'iconCls',            type:'string',      mapping:''}
]
});
```

**STORE**

```
Ext.define('strDocumentosTree', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model:  'mdlDocumentosTree',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax', 
    api: {read: 'some url'},
    reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
});
```

**VIEW**

```
var arbolcarpetas=new Ext.tree.Panel({
        itemId:'arbolcarpetas',
        title:'Archivos del Expediente',
        region:'west',
        width:250,
        collapsible:true,
        border: false,
        autoScroll:true,
        store:almacenDocumentos,
        rootVisible: false
    })
```

**CONTROLLER**

In the controller I load the tree store with this command:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewFichaDetalle #arbolcarpetas')[0].getStore().load();
```

And the php of the store is:

```
<?php
$x=0;
$nodes = array();
while($x<10){
    array_push($nodes,array('text'=>"A".$x, 'id'=>$x,'children'=>array('text'=>"A".rand(10,100),'id'=>$x,leaf=>true,'iconCls'=>'icon-excel')));
    $x++;
}
echo json_encode($nodes);
?>
```

The result is this infinite tree:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?Any clue?

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? When you do, please check whether the issue is that your model isn't derived from [`Ext.data.TreeModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeModel).

Comment: In your PHP code , what are you trying to achieve? Because ,there is no issues in ExtJS code what I feel , when ever you expand a node in a tree , the store url will get hit and that php code will execute and will return same set of nodes.

Comment: can u also post your response data?

Comment: I wanted to create the tree running only once the php,the fact is that when you expand one node,it executes the php again with the node property send to that php.So I am creating the tree like this,getting the node received and adding its leaves when expanding a node

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your response data should be under "data" tag because in your store you have mentioned root node as 'data' [root: 'data'] , But it seems that your are sending array of children node which are not under 'data' node. Kindly post your response data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Tree works like this if it is not leaf when you open it it requests the specified url. If it is a leaf then it stop sending the request. so in the backend you have to manage your response and you have to make leaf true for all the end nodes then it will work otherwise it will be infinite tree.

In your case first your requesting one api so server giving response but leafs of all the nodes are false.When you open A0 node again it requests the same url and will get the same response in that response all the leafs are false this continues forever.So you have to handle it in the backend that for all end nodes you have to make leaf true then it will work fine

Comment: I already got this problem and solved on my own if you want sample I will post my example code